# Power Query Table Headers Removing Text Before Delimiter

Tags: excel, powerquery

I am using Power Query (Get Data) in Excel to import data from a worksheet in another file. The source data is an OLAP pull and one of the member names (column header) is "Location.2 Area". It worked fine when I first set it up but now when I refresh the query is removing all text prior to the "." so it's just pulling as "2 Area" which is causing errors as future steps reference the column name.

Any ideas on how to fix this issue? Maybe it's a setting I'm not aware of?

Thanks!!

Comment: maybe there's been a change in your data?  Or an error in your code?

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow. I think it is good idea to post here some of your code (considering NDA).

Comment: Check first steps which query data from that table. If the data is fetched with new column names, then I agree with @RonRosenfeld, looks like the table was changed and you need to refactor your code.